# Convert a data.frame in "sparse matrix" COO format into an actual sparse-matrix class?

Tags: r, matrix

I am representing the following matrix:

```
6  5  0
0  5  4
0  0  4
```

as a data.frame.  The data.frame in R has three columns.  The COO format is as follows:

```
i  j  Xij
1  1  6
1  2  5
2  2  6
2  3  5
3  3  6
```

Note that there is no row `[1 3 0]` row, as it is omitted for having a value of *zero*.  The same applied for the lower-triangular values, which are also zero.

**What I want to do is** convert it into a `matrix.coo` or `dgCMatrix` class object from the `Matrix` package in R.

I do NOT want to convert it to a regular matrix first, as the dataset I am working with is very large, and writing a loop to convert it to a standard R matrix would take too long.

Comment: See `?"CsparseMatrix-class"`: I think you can probably figure out how to use `new("dgCMatrix",...)` to instantiate this directly ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `?Matrix::sparseMatrix` we can use the already-coded function as follows:

```
myMatrix <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = coo$i, j = coo$j, x = coo$Xij, dims = c(42, 42))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I tried with "new" (as @ben-bolker suggested) but this is more flexible and direct.